# How to generate git superproject from existing directory structure

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a current set up of a lots of git projects inside a huge directory tree. The structure looks something like this

```
projects
projects/stuff -> this is a git repo
projects/frontend/frontendone -> this is also a git repo
projects/frontend/frontendtwo -> this is also a git repo
projects/something -> this is a git repo
...
```

This whole tree contains a lot of git repos (like 50-100), they can be anywhere inside the tree, and they can be from different servers, with different configs.

I'd like to create a new superproject inside the `projects` directory that contains all of the repositories as submodules already there.

Most of the examples I could find on git submodules start with not having the git repository there, and re-adding them one-by-one with `git submodule add`, but I already have my directory structure set up nicely, and re-doing all of them one-by-one seems to be too much effort.

So basicaly I just want the `projects` directory to become a superproject and keep everything else intact where it is, as they are already set up nicely for me.

What is the easiest way to create the superproject?

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to get along without `git submodule add`. Still, you can cut quite a corner with `git submodule foreach`. What I found missing in the question, however, is do you want to keep submodules where they sit currently, or do you want to move them into a new place instead.

Comment: @raina77ow I want to keep them there (if possible), as that seems to be the easiest (for me). Although if that's not possible re-creating the whole structure externally and then moving it back here is also an option, but then I want to be able to re-create the structure without too much effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed the same answer, so I cooked up a script for Bash.  If you are on a different platform hopefully this illustrates what you need to do. Cheers!

```
#!/bin/bash
# add all the git folders below current folder as git submodules.
# NOTE: does not recursively nest submodules, but falls back to
# git submodule add's behavior of failing those.
# Workaround is to run this script in each affected directory
# from the bottom up.
# For example:
# a/.git
# b/.git
# b/b1/.git
# b/b2/.git
# c/.git
#
# run this script twice - first in b (adds b1 & b2 as submodules to b),
# then in root (adds a, b, c to root)
#

# if any options specified, treat as a test run and display only
if [ -z $1 ]; then
    GITSMADD="git submodule add -f"
    if [ ! -d ./.git ]; then
        git init
    fi
else
    GITSMADD="echo git submodule add -f"
    echo running in DISPLAY mode
fi

find . -name '.git' -type d -exec dirname {} \; | sort | while read LINE
do
    if [ "$LINE" != "." ]; then
        pushd $LINE > /dev/null
        ORIGIN=$(git remote -v | grep fetch | head -1 | awk '{print $1}')
        URL=$(git remote -v | grep fetch  | head -1 | awk '{print $2}')
        popd > /dev/null
        if [ -z $ORIGIN ]; then
            echo "Adding local folder $LINE as submodule."
            $GITSMADD "$LINE"
        else
            echo "Adding remote $URL as submodule in folder $LINE"
            $GITSMADD "$URL" "$LINE"
        fi

    fi
done
```